# Push Notifications in questions list

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to be notified when new questions arise. Would it be feasible? Receive notifications from a specific feed (in my case the Artificial Intelligence community)?

When I say "Notifications" I mean Push Notification (browser / mobile)

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that currently exists is the main Stack Exchange site's [filter/subscription feature](https://stackexchange.com/filters/). It doesn't do top bar push notifications as far as I know, but it can send new questions on a site to your e-mail as fast as every 15 minutes. You can also include multiple sites and filter by tags, if you like.